# SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set when executing SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I'm using using the sqljdbc4.jar (sqljdbc_2.0) version.

I'm executing an insert + a select back to get the identity like this:

```
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO DateRangeOptions (Description,Code) 
VALUES ('dateRange.quickPick.option.all','ALL');  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
END
```

and I get:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

The line is:

```
st.executeQuery(updateQuery)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not all drivers allow statement blocks to be executed as one query.  If this works in one and not another that is the likely culprit.

Comment: that would not be very prudent of Microsoft donnie, a select scope_identity() MUST happen before any other inserts and on a connection with the same job id. You can of course perform the queries back to back but it restricts how a open connection can be used by applications. Also SQL server has no problem executing multiple queries, and the driver is not T-SQL aware so it has no clue what it is executing. – Vainstah 0 secs ago

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgraded from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005 and switched to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver version 1.2. I got the error "The statement did not return a result" when executing an Insert followed by SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()".I solved the issue using executeUpdate() and getGeneratedKeys instead of executeQuery.  Here is the before and after code.

*Note: The connection used in this example is java.sql.connection not the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerConnection.*

**SQL 2000 code**

```
String  dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver" + "://" + dbServer + ":" +
                 dbServerPort + ";SelectedMethod=cursor;databaseName="
                           + dbName + ";user=xxx;password=xxx";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
sql = "insert into Contact (name) values ('ABC'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
     long id = rs.getLong(1);
     System.out.println("Id=" + id);
}
```

**SQL 2005 code**

```
String  dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver" + "://" + dbServer + ":" +
                 dbServerPort + ";SelectedMethod=cursor;databaseName="
                           + dbName + ";user=xxx;password=xxx";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
sql = "insert into Contact (name) values ('ABC'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.executeUpdate();  // do not use execute() here otherwise you may get the error
                     // The statement must be executed before 
                     // any results can be obtained on the next
                     // getGeneratedKeys statement.

ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
     long id = rs.getLong(1);
     System.out.println("Id=" + id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is really bizarre, and makes little sense.  I need to research why this works.

Answer (score 1):

The row you inserted failed therefore there is no identity ? set a breakpoint query is generated in Java copy out the query string and run it in management studio to see what the result is. This might show you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: ery odd, if the query is syntactically correct it should not casue a problem. Are the drivers plug-swappable ? The microsoft driver - might- require different initialization function calls. This is certainly the case with different ODBC drivers. Have you changed to the correct catalog ?

Answer (score 1):

Any option to upgrade the driver? Then you can just use `Statement#getGeneratedKeys()`. Also see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378445%28SQL.90%29.aspx

If that is not an option, then you need to fire the `INSERT` and `SELECT` separately after each other on the same connection.