# How do I get the resultset of a stored procedure in JPA?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jpa-2.0

I have SQL Server 2008 and a JPA (EclipseLink) app.  I need to be able to read the rows from the stored procedure.  The stored procedure does some updating/etc but at the end returns a

`select * from @result_table`

Now, when I access it in JPA using:

```
String sql = "exec up_GetUpdatedRows ?, ?, ?";
entityManager = Factories.getEntityManager();

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, myKey).setParameter(2, workDate).setParameter(3, createdBy);

List<Object[]> obj = query.getResultList();
```

I get the following **error**:

```
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

This works for other native SQL.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This does not appear to be related to JPA. This seems to be more related to the underlying JDBC driver. Check this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826271/sqlserverexception-the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set-when-executing-sql). This person reports the same problem as you. Perhaps the answers also works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found this answer.  I found it from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344631/does-jpa-2-0-support-sql-server-table-variables).

The problem was with not using `SET NOCOUNT ON`.  It was very confusing as the error said there were no result sets.  Yet, there appeared to be many.