# Does JPA 2.0 support SQL Server table variables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.0 and SQL Server 2008 and I have determined that JPA doesn't like my stored procedures when I use a table variable.

For example, this sproc works:

```
declare @t table
(
    id      int identity
,   test    varchar(50)
)

select 'blah' as test  -- I'm ignoring the table variable above
```

However, when I try to insert something into the table variable `@t` with this code, it crashes:

```
declare @t table
(
    id      int identity
,   test    varchar(50)
)

insert into @t
    select cast(getdate() as varchar(60))

select * from @t
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
Error Code: 0
```

I would hate to have to rewrite my complex sprocs to not use table variables if I can help it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: looks like in second case the stored procedures returns two result sets. the first is the result message of executing INSERT statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random thought: Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON.

Your code

```
insert into @t
    select cast(getdate() as varchar(60))

select * from @t
```

...will return this

```
(1 row(s) affected)
id          test
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Jun 14 2011  3:58PM

(1 row(s) affected)
```

There are actual *three* result "items" from SQL Server. The first has no assoicated result set.

... and a shameless plug of my question [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483732/27535) where breaking ORMs and such is mentioned because of this

Comment: BAM!  That was it.  +100000 if I could.  Thanks

Comment: nice catch! sql server ftf