# GAS returns "The statement did not return a result set" error

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am getting the error
 `The statement did not return a result set. (line 9, file "Code")` when  I execute the following script:

```
var ID = '0AgsrrAUVa01-dGVZVGhWekxsX3Fjieoww0RYMFA2VVE' //profiles
   function test() {
   var profile ="localSQLSERVER"    
   var conn = getConnection(profile,ID)
   var stmt = conn.createStatement();
   //var query = "exec sp_help"
   var query = "exec test.dbo.sp_dasboard_10" 
   var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);             
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
   conn.close();
   }
```

Knowing that the commented `exex sp_help` in the same script above does work fine.

The result in the proper Microsoft SQL Server  2000, also works fine and does not seem to return anything strange. Just the following result
 
numero de pasta
301 
284 
211 
144 
77  
77

The version of the SQL Server is:
version 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)   May 11 2012 18:41:14   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

In [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826271/sqlserverexception-the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set-when-executing-sql) I read that this can be solved by either using the `executeUpdate()` statement or by updating JDBC drivers for MS SQL.

Updating the driver is not an option using the JDBC service on Google Apps Script... 
And when I try other options like 
- `var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("exec test.dbo.sp_dasboard_10");` 
- put the sp in master 
All give the same error. 
and the test with
- `stmt.executeUpdate()` gives an error to add test in sysservers...

So any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Jacob, maybe it's just a typo? dashboard instead of dasboard? Anyway, what does this supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried `execute()` instead?

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu It is not a typo... I just used the wrong spelling to make sure I'm not interfering with some reserved word. The error would also be different `Could not find stored procedure 'test.dbo.sp_dashboard_10` And @mark Rotteveel as for the  `execute()` it returns false. I really suspect that I'll have to upgrade the sql server or write seperate queries to get to the result.

Comment: In the stored proc, are you doing a simple `SELECT` and returning the results? Are there other outputs are just a tabular response?

Comment: @ArunNagarajan The result is a simple select with the result above as output. This allthough in the messages it several times shows the message 1 row affected until it gets to the final result 6 rows affected. This as I have to do some preparation with themporary tables before I get to the final select. Also the detail that after the select I have to do the drop table #temp.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're still having the same issue after so many years but I want to show you all the solution my teammates and I found.

We had an SP like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GET_SOME_CARS
    @name VARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
        carName VARCHAR (50),
        carModel VARCHAR(50)
    );

    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    SELECT Name, Model
    FROM Cars
    WHERE Name = @name;

    SELECT *
    FROM #tempTable;

    DROP TABLE #tempTable;

END
```

When we tried to execute the same statement as you did (`executeQuery`), we got the same error: `The statement did not return a result set`.

After some time of searching in the code and doing some tests we found that the cause was simpler than we thought. It seems that some languages can't interpret the result set very well, if you look at the improvised code above you will notice there is an INSERT, the Stored Procedure returns a number of rows affected and the SELECT statement.

Then, Apps Script try to understand the response but it seems Apps Script can't do it, so that it returns `The statement did not return a result set.`. The solution was to add the statement `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the SP in order to avoid the return of affected rows, so that the code look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GET_SOME_CARS
    @name VARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- This is the added statement

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
        carName VARCHAR (50),
        carModel VARCHAR(50)
    );

    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    SELECT Name, Model
    FROM Cars
    WHERE Name = @name;

    SELECT *
    FROM #tempTable;

    DROP TABLE #tempTable;

END
```

Finally, our Apps Script's script started to work fine. We hope this solution works for you all.

Blessings!

P.S. We found the same problem with pyodbc (module for Python) if that works for you all as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found out if you use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`, it won't return error because it doesn't expect Result Set.

Why this happens is explained here [difference between execute, executeQuery and executeUpdate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/301594/JDBC/databases/Difference-execute-executeQuery-executeUpdate)

You should use it only when you're executing `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Ok I'll check this out!